# Make my google assistant call my REST API on specific words

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, api, google-assistant-sdk

Starting a new project (Rest api based on spring boot),, I would like to make it connected to Google.

Basically, I want, by saying specific words to google assistant, trigger a call on my REST API. For example, if I say "OK {myApiName}" and then "Do this", it will call a previously defined endpoint on my api as POST with "Do this" in the payload.

I've already checked the Google Actions API, but I am pretty lost...
Is this possible ? any advices ?

I'm in search of something easy to configure, Google can always trigger the same endpoint, I prefer to handle the interpretation of the payload myself.

Many thanks !

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to create something that is started from the Google Assistant. Is that correct? You say that you've checked the Actions API - was there something specific that is confusing to you? Stack Overflow works best when you have specific questions, or when you've tried something that doesn't work and you need help getting it to work. Broad questions can be difficult to answer - the more info you provide, the better chances we have to help. See [How do I Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure I understand why you want to make an API call from Google Assistant, but to do it, what you could do is build a [Conversational Aciton](https://developers.google.com/assistant/conversational/overview), that is an app for Google Assistant. It is possible to do it in a very simple and fast way using Dialogflow.

Dialogflow is an NLP that recognizes human language and "understands" what the user is asking for.

Within Dialogflow you can implement intents. An intent is used to associate a certain word or phrase with an "action".

In your case the phrase could be "OK {myApiName} do {this}" and the associated action would be to call {myApiName} with payload {this}.

In the "Dialogflow Fulfillment" you can implement the API call and return the result you want.

The flow is this:

[image]

To implement your intent you should do something like this: specify to Dialogflow "trainging phrases" that allow it to match the user's intention and encapsulate the payload in a "parameter". A parameter is nothing more than a variable that you will need to store the payload to be sent to your APIs.

[image]

At this point, just implement the fulfillment associated with your intent to make the API call with the related payload saved in the parameter. Something like this:

[image]

It is easier to do than to say. I hope I have given you an idea of how it works. I suggest you to read the documentation to better understand.

Comment: Since the conversational flow is being killed this June, I can't seem to find a similarly straightforward way to do this using the other templates.  Does anyone know?  Making a REST call through the Google Assistant seems to me one of the more valuable ways to extend it to one's personal needs.

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying this using [IFTT application](https://ifttt.com/explore/google-assistant-changes). There you can use Google assistant as a trigger for a webhook call.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).